# call multiple functions in onClick

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-component

I have this `span`:

```js
<span className="close" onClick={this.props.handleClose}><u>Close</u> X</span>
```

`handleClose` sets a property which is used to either show or hide a popup. I want to edit this `onClick` to also call a rest endpoint if `updateDocsFlag` is set to true by this function:

```js
doIsChecked() {
    var isItChecked = document.getElementById('isPless') as HTMLInputElement;

    if (isItChecked.checked) {
        this.setState({ updateDocsFlag: true });
    } else {
        this.setState({ updateDocsFlag: false });
    }
}
```

Can that be done? If so I assume if it can it'll be something like creating a function to make the rest call and including it in the `onClick` but I'm not sure if multiple functions can be called in this way.

`handleClose` comes from a different class. This is what it looks like:

```js
<Pless handleClose={this.hidePless} showPless={this.state.showPlessPrompt} />

hidePless = () => {
    this.setState({ showPlessPrompt: false });
};
```

In my Pless class I have this interface:

```js
interface Props {
    handleClose: () => void;
    showPless: boolean;
}
```

Comment: What is stopping you from creating a function `handleCloseClick()` that first calls `handleClose` then checks `updateDocsFlag` and calls the API when `true`?

Comment: They can be done. Please try and show us your code for handleClose and API call

Comment: OK trying that. If I just move `this.props.handleClose` to `handleCloseClick()` I get `unused expression, expected an assignment or function call`:

`handleCloseClick() {
    this.props.handleClose;
    if (this.state.updateEdocsFlag) {
        this.edocsService.updateEdocsStatus();
    }
}`

Comment: To call 2 functions, just call them inside `handleClose()`.

Comment: I added some info around `handleClose()` to my question as I'm not sure how I can call them inside it.

Comment: Sounds like you may have an issue with `this`. In that case, you would need to share more information, or ideally provide a live reproduction example, e.g. using CodeSandbox or StackBlitz.

Answer (score 2):

```
<span className="close" onClick={this.props.onclick}><u>Close</u> X</span>

// basically this is what you want no?
const onclick = () => {
    handleClose();
    doIsChecked();
};
```

If you need the event then you can pass it from the onclick function to the handleClose or doIsChecked

**Update:**

Actually the script above is more general. In your case it would probably look like this:

```
<span className="close" onClick={onclick}><u>Close</u> X</span>
```

.

```
const onclick = () => {
    this.props.handleClose();
    doIsChecked();
};
```